# Hide Wiki Page template from Site Actions>More Options in sharepoint 2010 programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-server, c-sharp

I want to hide the option of creating wiki page which is accessed via "Site Actions>More Options>Page" under Page type for all the users. I tried to find the display name and scope for deactivating the feature of "Wiki Page" but could not find it. Need to deactivate it programmatically using C#. How can I achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a feature and use `HideCustomAction` to hide the elements in the Standard Menu.

```
<HideCustomAction
   GroupId = "SiteActionsToolbar"
   HideActionId = "SiteActions"
   Id = "More Options"
   Location = "Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu">
</HideCustomAction>
```

The above is only pseudo code, you should find the appropriate Id values

Comment: I guess page template I am talking about is not in the standard menu. Currently, I am not able to get the name or GUID of the template to be removed.